# Submit button image overflowing - HTML

Tags: html, css

I've just created an image and am using it as a submit button:

```
 <input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/button.png" width="170" height="40" value="Sign up" class="loudbutton" />
```

However the **image is larger than it should be, it's flowing outside the images border (not css).**

You can see the example:

[image: odd submit button]

**All the blue outside of the black border should not show!**

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

You can see the full HTML at: http://jsfiddle.net/9vsLyhwg/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `padding: 7px;` from `.loudbutton, .quietbutton {`

```css
#submit {
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<body>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://secure.workbooks.com/resources/=QzM/workbooks_signup_form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.workbooks.com/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.workbooks.com/javascripts/jquery_validate.js"></script>
  <title>Signup to Workbooks</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() { $("#spinner").fadeOut("fast"); });
  </script>
</head><br>

<body>
  <div id="spinner"></div>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="main-body">
      <form id="customer_signup_form" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="edition" id="edition" value="trial"/>
        <input name="nickname" id="nickname" class="hide"/>
        <table>
        
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="first_name" id="first_name" class="required" minlength="2" size="40"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="last_name" id="last_name" class="required" minlength="2" size="40"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="email" id="email" class="required email" size="40"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="confirm_email">Email (Confirm)</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email" class="required email" equalTo='#email' size="40"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="job_role">Job Role</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select name="job_role" min="1">
  <option selected value="0">-- Please select one --</option>
  <option value="1775">Business Leader</option>
  <option value="1776">Customer Support: Leader</option>
  <option value="1777">Customer Support: Team Member</option>
  <option value="1778">Finance: Leader</option>
  <option value="1779">Finance: Team Member</option>
  <option value="1780">HR: Leader</option>
  <option value="1781">HR: Team Member</option>
  <option value="1782">Individual Contributor</option>
  <option value="1783">Industry Analyst</option>
  <option value="1784">Investment Analyst</option>
  <option value="1785">IT: Leader</option>
  <option value="1786">IT: Team Member</option>
  <option value="1787">Journalist</option>
  <option value="1788">Marketing: Leader</option>
  <option value="1789">Marketing: Team Member</option>
  <option value="1790">Office Manager / Assistant</option>
  <option value="1791">Operations: Leader</option>
  <option value="1792">Operations: Team Member</option>
  <option value="1793">Procurement Professional</option>
  <option value="1794">Purchasing: Leader</option>
  <option value="1795">Purchasing: Team member</option>
  <option value="1796">Sales: Leader</option>
  <option value="1798">Sales: Team Member</option>
</select>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="telephone" id="telephone" class="required" minlength="10" size="40"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="number_of_employees">Number of Employees</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="number_of_employees" id="number_of_employees" class="required integer" pattern="[0-9]*" size="7"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="company_name">Company Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="company_name" id="company_name" class="required" minlength="2" size="40"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="industry">Industry</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select name="industry" min="1">
  <option selected value="0">-- Please select one --</option>
  <option value="1721">Agriculture, Forestry &amp; Fishing</option>
  <option value="1722">Charity</option>
  <option value="1723">Construction</option>
  <option value="1725">Education &amp; Training</option>
  <option value="1726">Energy: B2B</option>
  <option value="1727">Energy: B2C</option>
  <option value="1728">Energy: Utilities</option>
  <option value="2204">Finance: General</option>
  <option value="1729">Finance: B2B</option>
  <option value="1730">Finance: B2C</option>
  <option value="1731">Finance: Investment Banking</option>
  <option value="1732">Finance: Retail Banking</option>
  <option value="1733">Government: Local</option>
  <option value="1734">Government: National</option>
  <option value="1735">Government: National, Local</option>
  <option value="1736">Health: B2C</option>
  <option value="1737">Health: Government</option>
  <option value="1738">Health: Social Care</option>
  <option value="1739">Hotels &amp; Restaurants</option>
  <option value="2205">Insurance: General</option>
  <option value="1740">Insurance: B2B</option>
  <option value="1741">Insurance: B2C</option>
  <option value="1799">IT &amp; Telecommunications: General</option>
  <option value="1742">IT &amp; Telecommunications: Hardware</option>
  <option value="1743">IT &amp; Telecommunications: Mobile Operators</option>
  <option value="1744">IT &amp; Telecommunications: National Carriers</option>
  <option value="1745">IT &amp; Telecommunications: Reseller/Integrator</option>
  <option value="1746">IT &amp; Telecommunications: Service Provider</option>
  <option value="1747">IT &amp; Telecommunications: Software</option>
  <option value="1748">IT &amp; Telecommunications: Vendor</option>
  <option value="1749">Leisure</option>
  <option value="1750">Manufacturing</option>
  <option value="1751">Media &amp; Publishing</option>
  <option value="1752">Mining &amp; Quarrying</option>
  <option value="1755">Real Estate</option>
  <option value="1756">Research &amp; Laboratories</option>
  <option value="1759">Services: Accounting</option>
  <option value="1760">Services: Advertising, Marketing &amp; Event Management</option>
  <option value="1762">Services: Consulting</option>
  <option value="1763">Services: Engineering, Architecture &amp; Design</option>
  <option value="1765">Services: Legal</option>
  <option value="2060">Services: Recruitment &amp; HR</option>
  <option value="1767">Services: Other</option>
  <option value="1768">Services: Personal Services</option>
  <option value="1769">Services: Professional Services</option>
  <option value="2062">Trade Association &amp; Professional Bodies</option>
  <option value="1772">Transport &amp; Logistics</option>
  <option value="1773">Water Supply, Sewerage &amp; Waste Management</option>
  <option value="1774">Wholesale, Retail &amp; Distribution</option>
</select>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="current_crm">Current CRM</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select name="current_crm" min="1">
  <option selected value="0">-- Please select one --</option>
  <option value="1503">Salesforce.com</option>
  <option value="2495">Microsoft Dynamics CRM Cloud</option>
  <option value="1042">Microsoft Dynamics CRM On Network</option>
  <option value="1232">Sugar CRM</option>
  <option value="1052">Sage CRM</option>
  <option value="1053">Saleslogix from Infor (ex Sage)</option>
  <option value="1234">Netsuite</option>
  <option value="1048">Spreadsheets / None</option>
  <option value="1054">Custom/In-house</option>
  <option value="2059">Other</option>
  <option value="1842">Workbooks</option>
  <option value="1504">Access Database</option>
  <option value="1051">ACT!</option>
  <option value="2157">Aderant CRM</option>
  <option value="2491">Base CRM</option>
  <option value="2100">Bluecube CRM</option>
  <option value="1512">Capsule</option>
  <option value="2489">CallPro</option>
  <option value="2199">CCH Central</option>
  <option value="2397">Charitylog</option>
  <option value="2409">CiviCRM</option>
  <option value="2092">Clarity</option>
  <option value="1507">ClickHQ</option>
  <option value="2263">Dealmaker (TAS Group)</option>
  <option value="1509">Exact</option>
  <option value="2099">FileMaker</option>
  <option value="2076">FileVision</option>
  <option value="2135">Frontline Data</option>
  <option value="1043">Goldmine</option>
  <option value="1046">Goldvision</option>
  <option value="1505">Highrise</option>
  <option value="2137">iMIS</option>
  <option value="1840">Industry Specific</option>
  <option value="1841">Insightly CRM</option>
  <option value="2122">Intouch CRM</option>
  <option value="1928">IRIS Integra</option>
  <option value="2305">Lagan CRM</option>
  <option value="2271">Lexis Nexis InterAction</option>
  <option value="1237">Link CRM</option>
  <option value="1930">Logical Office</option>
  <option value="1044">Maximizer</option>
  <option value="2505">Membrain</option>
  <option value="2513">Method CRM</option>
  <option value="1049">MS Outlook BCM</option>
  <option value="1236">Myoffice.net</option>
  <option value="1537">NetAge</option>
  <option value="2146">Nimble CRM</option>
  <option value="1983">Officetalk</option>
  <option value="2369">OOMI CRM</option>
  <option value="1610">Open CRM</option>
  <option value="2200">Only Considering Workbooks</option>
  <option value="2182">Onyx CRM</option>
  <option value="2106">Open Market</option>
  <option value="1510">Oracle</option>
  <option value="2327">Orchard CRM</option>
  <option value="2179">Pivotal CRM</option>
  <option value="2156">Progress CRM</option>
  <option value="1984">Prospectsoft</option>
  <option value="2155">ProTech</option>
  <option value="2102">Raisers Edge - Blackbaud</option>
  <option value="1047">Really Simple Systems</option>
  <option value="2139">Sage - Edition Unknown</option>
  <option value="1206">Salesforce.com - Enterprise Edition</option>
  <option value="1041">Salesforce.com - Group Edition</option>
  <option value="1205">Salesforce.com - Professional Edition</option>
  <option value="2121">Salesnet CRM</option>
  <option value="1541">SalesNexus</option>
  <option value="1444">Salesorder</option>
  <option value="1511">SAP</option>
  <option value="2181">Saratoga CRM</option>
  <option value="2493">Second CRM</option>
  <option value="2201">Siebel</option>
  <option value="1929">Shuttleworth</option>
  <option value="2105">Spirit</option>
  <option value="1985">Superoffiice</option>
  <option value="1648">Team Scope</option>
  <option value="2097">Technique MIS</option>
  <option value="2138">ThankQ</option>
  <option value="1229">Tracker RMS</option>
  <option value="1513">TSG MRM</option>
  <option value="2272">Union Square CRM</option>
  <option value="1839">VTiger</option>
  <option value="2159">Webchise</option>
  <option value="1050">WebCRM</option>
  <option value="1045">Zoho</option>
</select>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;
              
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="submit" id="submit" type="image" src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/button.png" width="170" height="40" value="Sign up" class="loudbutton" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        
        </table>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.extend($.validator.messages, {
          min: 'Please choose an option.'
        });
        $("#customer_signup_form").validate({
          submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('value', 'Registering.  Please wait...');
            document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
            form.submit();
          }
        });
        $("#customer_first_name").focus();
      });
      //]]>
      </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, out of interest. Why was my question down voted?

Answer (score 0):

In your workbooks_signup_form.css css file you have the .loudbutton declaration with...

```
background-color: rgb(79, 111, 163);
```

Remove that and the overflow color is removed.

Answer (score 0):

you have used this:

```
.loudbutton, .quietbutton {
color: #FFF;
border-radius: 0.5em;
background-color: #4F6FA3;
border: medium none;
padding: 7px;
margin: 10px 0px;
float: right;
}
```

remove `background-color: #4F6FA3;` and you are good to go.